# Grails GORM database mapping for unidirectional 1:n relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, mapping, grails-orm, cardinality

I am currently trying to create a new Grails application based on a legacy MySQL database. The application should only read information. The concrete DB schema uses for the specific domain classes a table per class hierarchy structure, as well as a property class to add new needed information to these classes.

Currently I cannot retrieve the property information for a `transation`. There is no exception, but I also cannot access the field `properties`. One problem I may face is, that the word `properties` is a keyword for Grails for the domain fields. But I need to use it because of the specific legacy table naming.

The legacy tables are named `transaction` and `transaction_properties`. One `transcation` can have muliple `transaction_properties`. The association is done via the key `transaction_id` in the `transaction_properties` table.

Table **transaction**

```
id  bigint(20)
transaction_id  varchar(255) (bad naming here, transaction_id is used to store additional meta information)
```

Table **transaction_properties**

```
transaction_id  bigint(20) -> referencing to transation.id
property_value  varchar(255)
property_key    varchar(32)
etc.
```

Domain class **Transaction**

```
class Transaction {

static hasMany = [properties : TransactionProperty]

static constraints = {
    //   transactionProperty unique: true
}

static mapping = {
    table "transaction"
    version false
    columns {
        id column : "id"
        beginDate column : "start"
        endDate column : "end"
        type column : "DTYPE"
        amount column : "total_amount"
        metaId column : "transaction_id"
        purchase column : "purchase_id"
        service column : "service_id"
        origin column : "origin_id"
        properties column : "id"
    }

}

Long id
Date beginDate
Date endDate
String type
String amount
String metaId

Purchase purchase
Origin origin
Service service
  etc.
  }
```

Domain class **TransactionProperty**

```
  class TransactionProperty {

static mapping = {
    table "transaction_properties"
    version false
    columns {
        id name : "transaction_id"
        key column : "property_key"
        value column : "property_value"
    }
}

String value
String key
Long id

def asString(){
    return "${key} = ${value}"
}
   }
```

Comment: Can't you just change hasMany = [properties: ...] to [transactionProperties: ...]?  You don't have any columns mapped to the word "properties".  It just tells Grails what the name of the collection should be.

Comment: When I do so, I get the following Exception. 
`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'kt-testing.transaction_transaction_properties' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a giant mess.

You need to add a `static belongsTo = [transaction: Transaction]` in your TransactionProperty domain class. This will tell grails to use the foreign key in that table instead of wanting a join table.

You also do not need to specify `Long id` in either table. That is done by default in Grails.

Remove these column mappings as well in the Transaction domain class:

```
id column : "id"
properties column : "id"
```

In TransactionProperty, it technically does not have a primary key (unless you are hiding it from us), so you will have to use a composite key of property_key and property_value.

```
id name : "transaction_id"
```

should be:

```
id composite: ['key', 'value']
```

Read up on the additional requirements of this here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.5.2.5%20Composite%20Primary%20Keys

My best attempt at fixing your classes:

Transaction:

```
class Transaction {

static hasMany = [properties : TransactionProperty]

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {
    table "transaction"
    version false
    columns {
        beginDate column : "start"
        endDate column : "end"
        type column : "DTYPE"
        amount column : "total_amount"
        metaId column : "transaction_id"
        purchase column : "purchase_id"
        service column : "service_id"
        origin column : "origin_id"
    }

}

Date beginDate
Date endDate
String type
String amount
String metaId

Purchase purchase
Origin origin
Service service

}
```

TransactionProperty:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class TransactionProperty implements Serializable {

static belongsTo = [transaction: Transaction]

static mapping = {
    table "transaction_properties"
    version false
    columns {
        key column : "property_key"
        value column : "property_value"
    }
}

String value
String key


def toString(){
    return "${key} = ${value}"
}

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof TransactionProperty)) {
        return false
    }

    other.key == key && other.value == value
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    builder.append key
    builder.append value
    builder.toHashCode()
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I hope to find some days over the christmas days to read the Grails in Action book, I surely need to. This fixed my problem: `class TransactionProperty implements Serializable{

 static mapping = {
  table "transaction_properties"
  id composite: ['key', 'value']
  version false
  columns {
   key column : "property_key"
   value column : "property_value"
  }
 }`